# Unable to merge dex in AS 3.0 after updating Lombok

Tags: android, android-studio, dex, lombok, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading to AS 3.0, and subsequently updating Lombok to be with 'annotationProcessor' as well as 'compileOnly', I get the 'unable to merge dex' exception that many are experiencing with the AS version release. When I run stacktrace, it alerts me of duplicate files in a jar I'm using in the library module...BUT the 2 files are for the release (releaseCompile) and debug (debugCompile) builds separately, so why is this an error?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: yes. all the usual procedures were taken, as well as any suggestions given for similar posts. and yes multiDexEnabled is set to true.